# Cannot convert value of type 'CGRect' to expected argument type 'NSCoder'

Tags: swift, xcode

I can't seem to resolve this error on Swift 3.0, Xcode 8.0. 
Here's the code for reference:

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

class TimerViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Set Title
        title = "Timer"
        let scene1 = CountdownViewController(coder: view.bounds.self)
        let skView = view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        skView.presentScene(scene1)


    }

}
```

The line that's giving me the error is this one:

```
let scene1 = CountdownViewController(coder: view.bounds.self)
```

I don't understand how to change it. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `UIViewController init?(coder:)`.

Comment: do I replace this: let scene1 = CountdownViewController(coder: view.bounds.self) with init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)

Comment: No, you need to pass an `NSCoder` argument to the `coder` parameter instead of trying to pass a `CGRect` argument to the `coder` parameter.